# How can I reset to default blueprint my variables?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I want to reset my variables in code C++ as default blueprint like UE4 Editor does when you press the yellow arrow in editor

[image]

Does anyone know how can I make it? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any UObject you can retrieve the default object. For example,

```
APawn const* DefaultPawn = APawn::StaticClass()->GetDefaultObject<APawn>();
```

This object will have the default values for that C++ class. If you have your blueprint class and you want to find the first native (C++) class in its hierarchy you might want to take a look at

```
UClass::IsNative
```

Comment: So if I want to get the Blueprint class of an UObject so I can get its DefaultObject, what I need to do?

Comment: If you want the blueprint (generated) class, you use MyObject->GetClass() instead of AMyObject::StaticClass()